# How to add items in picker list after UI rendering

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, picker

what I am trying to do is that I want to add list of Provinces i.e. States of Country which I am receiving from an API call ([THIS](https://www.btsp.ml/api/citizen/states)). But obviously it takes time to call and receive data from API. Now how do I put this list in picker items.

My code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    Picker,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

import GLOBAL_STYLES from "../constants/GLOBAL_STYLES";

const RegisterScreen = props => {
    let [stateSelectedValue, setStateSelectedValue] = useState("Select State");
    let [citySelectedValue, setCitySelectedValue] = useState("Select City");
    let provinces = [], cities = []

    async function gettingStatesAsync() {
        let response = await fetch('https://www.btsp.ml/api/citizen/states')
        provinces = await response.json().data.states

        console.log(provinces)
    }

    const StatesAsync = gettingStatesAsync();

    async function gettingCities() {
        let response = await fetch('https://www.btsp.ml/api/citizen/states/' + 1 + '/cities')
        cities = await response.json().data.cities

        console.log(cities)
    }

    let provincesList = () => {
        return (provinces.map((x, i) => {
            return (<Picker.Item label={x} key={i} value={x}/>)
        }));
    }

    return (
        <View style={GLOBAL_STYLES.authScreen}>
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
                
                <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginStart: 10, marginEnd: 10}}>
                        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                            <Picker
                                selectedValue={stateSelectedValue}
                                style={{height: 30, justifyContent: 'flex-start', color: '#fff'}}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setStateSelectedValue(itemValue)}
                                mode={"dropdown"}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label="Select State" value=""/>
                                {provincesList()}
                            </Picker>
                        </View>

                        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                            <Picker
                                selectedValue={citySelectedValue}
                                style={{height: 30, justifyContent: 'flex-end', color: '#fff'}}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setCitySelectedValue(itemValue)}
                            >
                                <Picker.Item label="Select City" value=""/>
                                <Picker.Item label="Islamabad" value="isb"/>
                                <Picker.Item label="Hasilpur" value="hsp"/>
                                <Picker.Item label="Rawalpindi" value="pindi"/>
                            </Picker>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default RegisterScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    successTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 18,
        padding: 30,
    },
});
```

It is receiving the data from API, but how do I add these to picker item after rendering UI because it is causing the issue? What am I doing wrong? If I add provinces in `provinces object`, it adds to Picker Item but not with API call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain the provinces in a state like below

```
const [provinces,setProvinces] = useState([]);

    async function gettingStatesAsync() {
        let response = await fetch('https://www.btsp.ml/api/citizen/states')
        const data = await response.json().data.states
        setProvinces(data);
    }
```

Then it would re render when the provinces array is updated with data from API.